# CSS Sub Menu Padding Issue

Tags: css

I am having an issue with a sub menu.  You can see at http://responsiveradio.radiobrandbuilders.com by hovering over the Home link.

The padding does not show up for the sub menu li a items but as soon as you hover over them the padding works.

I'm sure it is something simple I am overlooking but any help would be appreciated.

```
nav {
  height: 60px;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 19px;
  padding: 0;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
nav li a {
 color: #000;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 500;
 padding: 15px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
nav li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  width: 200px;
 }
 .sub-menu li {
   display: block;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }
  .sub-menu li a {
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .sub-menu li a:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
  }
```

Comment: padding is set to 0 in your submenu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes in your css to be made... A tag is inline tag ...so you have to make is display block.

```
nav li a {
color: #000;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 500;
padding: 15px;
text-transform: uppercase;
display: block;               /*changes done */
}
nav ul {
list-style: none;

padding: 0;
margin-top: 0; /*changes done */
}
.sub-menu{
display: none;
left: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 52px;            /*changes done */
width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in css

```
 .sub-menu li{

    padding:15px;

 }
```

In your css you set padding:0px;

Answer (score 0):

modify your style like

```
.sub-menu li a {
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.sub-menu li a{padding:0}
```

add this style and refresh your page.